# Scilab - define a function inside another one

Tags: function, scilab

I want to define a function that takes an input *n* and gives back the function *f* defined by *f(x) = x^n*.

So I wrote the following piece of code on Scilab:

```
function [f]=monomial(n)
    function [z] = g(x)
        z = x^n
    endfunction
    f = g
endfunction
```

Unfortunately when I evaluate `monomial(3)(2)` I get `32.` whereas it should be `8.`

I hope someone could point out where I have gone wrong when writing this function.

Could somebody help me please?

---

I cleared all variables and reran the code and it told me that n is not defined within g, therefore is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: In Scilab you can return a function `f` as result of `g`, but if `f` is defined inside `g`, `f` does not see the variables bound in the scope of `g` but I does see variables bound in the global scope, which I think is an inconsistent behavior that should be corrected.

Comment: Try this: put `global n` inside `monomial` and before `g`, then `global n` inside `g`. It will work for the first call, and the first call only. After that, the value of `n` won't change. That is very weird to me.

Comment: @luispauloml Thanks for looking at my problem, I tried to do as you suggested and ended up with the same confusion. It goes well the first time then it gets stuck at the initial answer.

Comment: Why defining things in this nested way, instead of a direct definition
    `function z = monomial(x,n),  z = x^n;  endfunction` and call `monomial(2,3)`
?

Comment: @S.Gougeon I did not want a power function but rather a function that returns a polynomial function of a given degree. So the output I was looking for was not a float, otherwise I would have done what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the more secure way to do this is by using `deff` :

```
function [f]=monomial(n)
    f = deff('z=g(x)','z=x^'+string(n));
endfunction
```

otherwise `n` could be polluted by current scope

```
--> monomial(2)(8)
 ans  =

   64.
```

Comment: Thank you for your very useful and efficient answer! It works like a charm now.

Comment: Great. Variable scope in Scilab is a nightmare...